# How to search string field in MySQL which contain two or more words separated by space?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, select

I have some old DB where I did not put some restrictions for inserting names through web PHP form. Now I have put them there to be only single word not two words or more. There are 10 000 rows now after the years in that DB.

Example field in DB: "John Doe Blue"
With new rules user can only fill in "JohnDoeBlue"

Is there any way how to Select all cases where I have names which do not contain only single word but multiple in that string field? My new function which prevents wrong or multiple words in the field is this:

```
  public function wrongName($name)
  {
    return !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$/", $name);
  }
```

How can I select from DB all cases which do not meet this function but are already existing in the DB?

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Try `name LIKE "% %"`. In other words search for values containing Space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove any spaces from a column containing data like this `"John Doe Blue"` all you need to do is

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, ' ','');
```

If you want to check that you are only getting the rows you want before doing the update try

```
SELECT column, REPLACE(column, ' ','') as potentialNewColumn
FROM table 
WHERE INSTR(column, ' ') > 0 ;
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work! Is there any select to also check special characters? I mean different from the condition above a-z, A-Z, 0-9? Characters like ä etc and replace them the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The following query could be used to replace and search.

`select * from table where REPLACE (column,' ','') like '%your value%':`